# Rails 5 Message Chat tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, redis, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm going through the rails 5 tutorial to build a message chat. I was doing so well until I came across the below error when I am trying to view is using localhost 3000.

```
>**uninitialized constant HomeController** 

>Routes match in priority from top to bottom

>Helper HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
>Path / Url     
>Path Match
>/cable 
>#>, @pubsub=nil, @worker_pool=nil, @event_loop=nil, >@remote_connections=nil, @connections=[]>

>new_user_session_path  GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    
devise/sessions#new

>user_session_path  POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    
devise/sessions#create

>destroy_user_session_path  DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   
>devise/sessions#destroy

>user_password_path POST    /users/password(.:format)   
>devise/passwords#create

>new_user_password_path GET /users/password/new(.:format)   
>devise/passwords#new

>edit_user_password_path    GET /users/password/edit(.:format)  
>devise/passwords#edit

>PATCH  /users/password(.:format)   
>devise/passwords#update

>PUT    /users/password(.:format)   
>devise/passwords#update

>cancel_user_registration_path  GET /users/cancel(.:format) 
>devise/registrations#cancel

>user_registration_path POST    /users(.:format)    
>devise/registrations#create

>new_user_registration_path GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    
>devise/registrations#new

>edit_user_registration_path    GET /users/edit(.:format)   
>devise/registrations#edit

>PATCH  /users(.:format)    
>devise/registrations#update

>PUT    /users(.:format)    
>devise/registrations#update

>DELETE /users(.:format)    
>devise/registrations#destroy

>root_path  GET /   
>home#index

>chat_rooms_path    GET /chat_rooms(.:format)   
>chat_rooms#index

>POST   /chat_rooms(.:format)   
>chat_rooms#create

>new_chat_room_path GET /chat_rooms/new(.:format)   
>chat_rooms#new

>chat_room_path GET /chat_rooms/:id(.:format)   
>chat_rooms#show

>GET    /   
>chat_rooms#index
```

I have gone through it step by step but it's still not showing anything? Any advice would be ace. I'm new to rails so bere with me :)

Basically I just want to view it on the server :( so any help would be superb.

Comment: The error message indicates that somewhere in your code, there's a thing called HomeController that you're trying to use, but Rails doesn't know what that is.  Do you have a file `app/controllers/home_controller.rb` - and if so, is it correct? Also, search your codebase for that string and find where it's being referenced.

Comment: Hi John, No I don't have that file in controllers. Shall I make one? What should I put in it? I literally followed it step by step?

Comment: Don't add that file if it doesn't exist.  But search your code for the string "HomeController".  Something somewhere is trying to reference that.

Comment: If you link to the tutorial you follow it might help us get more information. But as John mentioned, your code is looking for a HomeController - which doesn't exist. Depending on your situation you either need to create it, or rework the code that's calling it.

Comment: Guys thank you so much for both getting back to me. So here is the tutorial I'm following https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/

Comment: yep John and Marcus just checked and I can't find anything called HomeController?

Comment: Can you add the full error stack to your question, please?